# Relative paths with BIBINPUTS

Tags: bibtex

I have a common `references.bib` file for several papers, so my `paper1/main.tex` refers to that bibliography like this:

```
\bibliography{../references}
```

This works great when I am in the `paper1` directory. However, I am trying to compile the paper in a different directory (say, `/tmp`). I have copied the all of the TeX files from `paper1` to there and would like `bibtex` to find my bibliography by setting the `BIBINPUTS` environment variable:

```
BIBINPUTS="/home/papers/paper1/" bibtex main.aux
```

This isn't working; somehow, `bibtex` can't find `/home/papers/paper1/../references.bib`, even though it exists.

What's going on, and what can I do to get `bibtex` to find my references?

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2017 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Running the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` should give you the path to the root of your personal texmf tree. If that tree doesn't exist create it. From there create the directory structure bibtex/bib and place your .bib file in that directory. It should then be found with no additional input needed.

Comment: I'm sure that would work, but I would really like a solution that does not involve moving my bib files.

Comment: Try making symbolic links instead of moving the files themselves.

Comment: I came across the same annoying problem. One way I was able to solve this is to have a directory inside `paper1` say `auto` then specify that bib path as `auto/../../references`, not ideal but works. I think `bibtex` handles `..` differently to other paths.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this is a bug in how bibtex handles `BIBINPUTS`, as indeed the [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406024/relative-paths-with-bibinputs#comment1388120_406024) by @Tohiko does work.

However, since you are using `BIBINPUTS` anyway to specify the location of the bibliography file, why not just do `\bibliography{references}` and then `BIBINPUTS=/home/papers bibtex main`?

Then bibtex will search the file in `/home/papers/references.bib` instead of `/home/papers/paper1/../references.bib`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem anymore, maybe it has been fixed?